# Error al insertar datos en mysql desde java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Al momento de querer mandar la información a la base de datos desde netbeans no me deja y  me aparece el error de la imagen, e visto miles de vídeos y nada mas no puedo por mas que le cambio y modifico!, necesito crear una base de datos que guarde y lea información sobre datos del alumno como calificación, se podrá decir que el código ya esta, solo la conexión me falla.

este es el error que me marca Conexion exitosa

> may 25, 2017 12:41:44 PM Frames.PantallaPrincipal
>   jButton1ActionPerformed GRAVE: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'Paterno,Apellido Materno,Calificación,Matricula)
>   VALUES'Joel''Hernandez''Alvara' at line 1 at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ‌​e
>   Method)

Es lo principal que me marca al querer guardar los datos 
y esto es lo que tengo en mi JFrame
package Frames;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Wendu
 */
public class PantallaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   ConexionBD con = new ConexionBD();
   Connection cn = con.conexion();

    public PantallaPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtnombre = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtapellidopat = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtapellidomat = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtcali = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtmat = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 204));
        jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));

        jTabbedPane1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 153));

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 153, 204));

        jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Frames/ffff.jpg"))); // NOI18N

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 586, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 280, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(20, 20, 20))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Inicio", jPanel1);

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 153));
        jPanel3.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Nuevo Registro"));
        jPanel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255));

        jLabel2.setText("Nombre");

        jLabel3.setText("Apellido Paterno");

        jLabel4.setText("Apellido Materno");

        jLabel5.setText("Calificación");

        jLabel6.setText("Matricula");

        jButton1.setText("Guardar");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(119, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)))
                            .addComponent(jLabel6))
                        .addGap(61, 61, 61)
                        .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(txtapellidopat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtnombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtapellidomat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtcali, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(txtmat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 160, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(174, 174, 174))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 105, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(71, 71, 71))))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(txtnombre, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(txtapellidopat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(txtapellidomat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtcali, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(txtmat, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(55, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Registro/Consulta", jPanel3);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jTabbedPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

       try {
           PreparedStatement pps;
           pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarioo(Nombre,Apellido Paterno,Apellido Materno,Calificación,Matricula) VALUES?????");
           pps.setString(1,txtnombre.getText());
           pps.setString(2,txtapellidopat.getText());
           pps.setString(3,txtapellidomat.getText());
           pps.setString(4,txtcali.getText());
           pps.setString(5,txtmat.getText());
           pps.executeUpdate();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Datos guardados");


       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(PantallaPrincipal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }

    }
```

Y en la principal para la conexión es esto

```
package Frames;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author Wendu
 */
public class ConexionBD {
     Connection cn;
     Statement st;

     public Connection conexion(){
         try{
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/Usuarioo?user=root&password=");
         Statement stm = cn.createStatement();
         System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
     }return cn;
}
    Statement createStatement(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No soportado");
    }
}
```

el erro es este

Conexion exitosa
may 25, 2017 1:15:42 PM Frames.PantallaPrincipal jButton1ActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Materno,Calificación,Matricula) VALUES('Joel','Hernandez','Alvarado','80','1698' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at Frames.PantallaPrincipal.jButton1ActionPerformed(PantallaPrincipal.java:195)
    at Frames.PantallaPrincipal.access$000(PantallaPrincipal.java:14)
    at Frames.PantallaPrincipal$1.actionPerformed(PantallaPrincipal.java:91)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: hace falta más información para responder tu pregunta

Comment: y el código de conexión cual es

Comment: este es el error que me marca Conexion exitosa
may 25, 2017 12:41:44 PM Frames.PantallaPrincipal jButton1ActionPerformed
GRAVE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Paterno,Apellido Materno,Calificación,Matricula) VALUES'Joel''Hernandez''Alvara' at line 1
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) Es lo principal que me marca al querer guardar los datos

Comment: Ahora falta que muestres el codigo que inserta en la base

Comment: Agrega por favor confirmar tienes construido el código de insert y como le envías los parámetros. Tú error es porque hay un error de sintaxis.

Comment: Yo diría que menos vídeos y más lectura. Nunca he podido aprender programación viendo vídeos , prefiero leer. El error parece indicar que tu SQL de inserción es errónea. Aquí puedes leer varios ejemplos de cómo se construye una cadena de inserción y como se envía a la BD: http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/jdbc/jdbc0002 Nuestra generación de la imagen debe volver a la **lectura**.

Comment: podrías ser un poco mas especifico por favor

Comment: pues si, tienes razon A.Cedano, solo que a falta de tiempo me fui a lo "rapido", gracias

Answer (score 2):

Me parece extraño que tengas en tu tabla **nombres de columnas con espacios y con carácteres especiales como acentos**, en realidad no se me había ocurrido y sería interesante verificar si esto funciona. Aunque funcione, **no es recomendable**, yo eliminaría los espacios, acentos y caracteres especiales en los nombres de columna, me refiero no sólo a la cadena INSERT INTO, sino a cambiar esos nombres de columna en las tablas de la base de datos.

Yo haría mi código de inserción de la siguiente manera, **usaré nombres de columnas más adecuados**... y suponiendo que no es un error de escritura, que tu tabla se llama `usuarioo` y no `usuario` ..., verifica y corrige si es necesario.

```
//Prefiero usar variables, para más claridad de código ...

String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO usuarioo " 
                 + "(Nombre, ApellidoPaterno, ApellidoMaterno, Calificacion, Matricula) "
                 + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";

   try {
       PreparedStatement pps;
       pps = cn.prepareStatement(insertSQL);
       pps.setString(1,txtnombre.getText());
       pps.setString(2,txtapellidopat.getText());
       pps.setString(3,txtapellidomat.getText());
       pps.setString(4,txtcali.getText());
       pps.setString(5,txtmat.getText());
       pps.executeUpdate();

... resto del código
```

Debe funcionar, si corriges tus nombres de columna, si la conexión se hace correctamente y si los diferentes `pps.set...` corresponden al tipo de dato con que ha sido declarada cada columna en la base de datos.

P.D.: Si no estás usando conexiones persistentes o reutilizas la conexión piensa en hacer los cierres correspondientes en un bloque `finally`. [Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo completo](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/).

Comment: gracias @A.Cedano hice las correciones pero me aparece que mi tabla no existe ahora

Comment: Pero verifica como se llama tu tabla **en la base de datos** y ponle el mismo nombre en el INSERT INTO ...

Answer (score 1):

Esto esta incorrecto

```
pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarioo(Nombre,Apellido Paterno,Apellido Materno,Calificación,Matricula) VALUES?????");
```

Debes cambiarlo por

```
pps = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO usuarioo(Nombre,`Apellido Paterno`,`Apellido Materno`,Calificación,Matricula) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Y no se si tengas un error en el nombre de tu tabla `usuarioo`

Aqui hay un [tutorial completo](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/) (en inglés)

Comment: El espacio en "apellido Paterno" es válido?

Comment: @ArieCwHat Nopes, o almenos no asi, no lo note, se puede usar comillas

Comment: Si lo se, pero era un forma sutil de corregirte  :)

Comment: @ArieCwHat Gracias :)

Comment: hice las correcciones pero me sigue apareciendo error, hasta cambie la misma tabla de nombre y me apareció esto

Comment: lo mismo que al principio y esto despues
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

Comment: @WendyHernandez es el mismo error? puedes editar tu pregunta y publicarlo ahi para que todos lo veamos

Comment: @jasilva ya hice el cambio y ahí esta el error que me marca

Comment: @WendyHernandez Si agregaste las comillas ``` tambien puedes usar parentesis cuadrado `[` de la siguiente forma `[Apellido Paterno]` trata de asegurarte como se llaman tus campos para que la consulta funcione adecuadamente